# Unable to locate element: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I am writing script for mobile number verification by One time password (OTP). While OTP popup is open, I am unable to put value in the text field, system is showing error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"class name","selector":"opt_success"} Command duration or
>   timeout: 30.04 seconds"

Below is the code that I have drafted.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys(Constants.MOBILE_NUMBER);
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_verify")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement otp_value = driver.findElement(By.id("otp"));
        otp_value.sendKeys("1212121212");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/form/div/div[4]/span[1]/input")).click();
```

Webpage url is : http://talentrack.in/register

Comment: The error is not from your code in question. Could you show us the line that call `findElement(by.className("opt_success"))` ?

Comment: Buaban is right. The code you've shown cannot result in the error you've shown. There is more code you have, show it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***You need to correct your Xpath for "OTP text field" as below.***

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@id='otp']")).sendKeys("1212121212");
```

Also, you can use 'relative' xpath for Submit button instead of using 'absolute' xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@type='submit']")).click();
```

Comment: Really helpful and it is working fine! thanks Srikanth

Answer (score 0):

```java
WebElement otp_value = driver.findElement(By.id("otp"));
```

This here is your problem. On the page there are 2 elements with the id "otp". You are finding the first one which is hidden, but you need the second one.

You could use a WebDriverWait to find the visible element. I did this in Python like so:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "otp")))
return element
```

The timeout of 0 that is passed to the WebDriverWait means that it will only try and find the element one time. You could make a method that does this and pass it a timeout parameter for easy reuseability.

I'm sure there is a Java equivalent for this.
Alternatively you could use a different locator that is unique to the element.

Comment: `find_visible_element`? Are you sure there is this method in python-selenium? :)

Comment: @alecxe You're right that was a method I've created myself. I've fixed the answer but I just noticed Buaban's comment saying the error isn't the code shown and he is right. So I guess this isn't the correct answer either way.